# How to remove WordPress menu bar form site?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My word is done, but the WordPress menu is visible on Woocommerce MyAccount page. If I log in as a customer then this top menu appears on the screen. How can i remove or disable the top WordPress menu?
[image]

Comment: That is not normal… By default, only woocommerce **customer** user role, doesn't see the admin to menu bar. So something is making trouble in your website. If you are using some other user roles than "customer", this admin top menu bar appears.

Comment: I guess you are logged in with your default wordpress site back-end login credentials and that is why that admin bar is showing up.